# How can I install tactile audio keys on my latitude?

Tags: drivers, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a Dell latitude 6430u which has three tactile keys for mute/audio decrease/audio increase.

On debian (sid), either with xfce or gnome, these keys don't work well. The mute key has never work. The two others work sometimes, but not well (I have to press twice, sometimes nothing happens, ...)

Is it possible to have a better support for these keys? I don't know anything about drivers for tactile keys.

When I use `xev` and using this shortcut I've got:

```
FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Gnome the easiest way is to run gnome-keybinding-properties (System > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts)

Instead of typing a shortcut such as Ctrl+M, hit the button on your keyboard.  Type in the command below for the 'Mute' key:

```
amixer sset Master toggle
```

Volume Up:

```
amixer -c 0 set Master 1+ unmute
```

Volume Down:

```
amixer -c 0 set Master 1-
```

Of course if that is increasing or decreasing the volume too slowly you can change the number in front of the + or - sign.

Comment: The problem is these keys are not properly recognized. They work sometimes, so I don't need to tell them what to do (increase/decrease). I guess it's a driver problem not a key assignment one.